# Cоздание и распространение пакета PHP+JS

Tags: php, javascript, npm, composer, bower

Есть простая фреймворконезависимая библиотека на PHP для вывода статистики. К ней есть фронтенд, строящий диаграммы на JS+CSS, требующий еще и Сhart.js в зависимостях. Как распространять данную связку целиком? Сразу говорю, что бэкенд без фронтенда хоть и будет работать, но вряд ли кому-то пригодится. Весь цимес именно в связке.

Пока в голову пришли только такие варианты.

1. Все вместе - PHP+JS+СSS через Сomposer и какой-нибудь asset-менеджер.
2. Разбить на два репозитория и распространять бэкенд - через Сomposer, а фронтенд через NPM/Bower.
3. Использовать один репозиторий, но фронтенд ставить через NPM/Bower, а бэкенд через Сomposer.

Может есть еще способы? Как обычно распространяются подобные проекты?

Comment: на кого ориентирован этот пакет? кто его пользователь?

Comment: В первую очередь - СRM, дашборды. Но каких-то узких рамок у него нет. Прикрутить можно куда угодно.

Comment: не куда! а кто? разработчик? администратор? интегратор? пр?

Comment: Менеджеры, экономисты. Там текущая экономическая статистика.

Comment: тогда вам надо написать для них очень подробную инструкцию. так как они вряд ли знают о менеджерах зависимостей и пр.

Comment: Я не предполагаю, что пользователи будут его устанавливать. Пользователи получат график и три кнопки. А устанавливать его будут разработчики, администраторы, интеграторы.

Comment: тогда инструкция может быть проще. выкладывает его на github (например) и описываете как его подключить. в принципе вы можете написать небольшой скрипт, который внесет необходимые зависимости в правильные файлы. но главное - это инструкция.

Comment: Вот я и спрашиваю через какие пакетные менеджеры его распространять, как оформить пакет, чтобы знать какую именно инструкцию подключения написать.

Comment: Разница между NPM и Bower в том, что NPM используется для серверной части, а Bower для клиентской. То есть в Вашем случае NPM не подходит

Comment: А в чём проблема распостранять архивом - готоввый продукт с демками целиком?) Думаете потенциальным клиентом нужен геморой с установкой? Или вопрос с авторскими правами вас беспокоит?

Comment: А бэкенд и фронтенд обязательно должны работать на одной машине? Если нет, то их нельзя объединять в один пакет.

Comment: Дык, если распространять архивом, геморроя точно будет больше. Пакетные менеджеры зачем-то ж придумали? По крайней мере, ставя через Composer я хоть точно буду знать где лежит файл. Да, бэкенд и фронтенд должны работать на одной машине.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Давайте так рассуждать: фронтэнд от вашей библиотеки по-отдельности бесполезен.

Поэтому вижу только вариант распространения через Composer, с выкладкой кода на Github. Какую-то работоспособную версию Chart.js, конечно, прикладывайте к проекту, [лицензия MIT](http://www.chartjs.org/docs/latest/notes/license.html) это [позволяет](https://habrahabr.ru/post/284396/).

Для удобства обновления Chart.js можно приложить и package.json, отметив этот факт в Readme.

Так можно получить из одного источника работоспособную библиотеку и сразу начинать ее использовать.

Comment: Спасибо. Да, так будет лучше всего.

Answer (score -2):

Думаю в данной формулировке - никак!!!. 
Как данная независимая библиотека будет работать с разными системами, фреймворками и по-разному настроенными php и настроенными rewrite rul-ами??? Я уже не говорю о получении и хранении данных с SQL и не-SQL решениями.

Думаю в данном случае хорошо подойдем виджет, который будет генерироваться где-то на вашем сайте/сервере. И каждому, кто хочет пользоваться будем отдаваться js-файл и соответственно код для вставки в нужном месте.

Comment: В плане PHP - ставим через Сomposer в папку vendor и подключаем в нужный контроллер. Я, конечно, понимаю, что есть те, кто ничего не слышал про стандарты, но это уже их проблемы. JS менее стандартизирован, пакеты все ставят куда хотят, собирают как хотят, но ведь поэтому я и задал этот вопрос. SQL там нет вообще. Данные берутся из API. Если реализовать как виджет, то придется все равно подгружать Сhart.js. А это пункт первый. Asset-менеджер?

Comment: Вы предлагаете из библиотеки сделать сервис?

Comment: Я предлагаю из библиотеки сделать виджет.